# reverse and remove letters in vowel positions in a string in java

Tags: java

for eg if string is "pond"then it should print "dop" as the output
note:vowel positions must take from original string
my code is
import java.util.Scanner;

public class vowelpositionremove {

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    java.lang.String s,m="";
    int i,j=0;
    int []a=new int[100];
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    s=sc.nextLine();
    for(i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        m=m+s.charAt(i);

    }
    for(i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)=='a'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='u'){
            for( j=0;j<s.length()-1;j++){
        a[j]=i;
        break;
        }

    }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++){

        if(i!=a[j]){
            System.out.print(m.charAt(i));

        }
    }


}
```

}

but it is not working how to modify this

Comment: .equals() for non integer comparison ie string/char, == is for comparing integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedo code for ya

```
stack=Stack
for( i=0, (i in length(input))-1)
    input[i].push(Stack)


string  finalString =""
while stack!= empty
    nextChar= Stack.pop()
    finalString.append(nextChar)
```